# Number of rows affected by SQL statement using Aqua Data Studio

Tags: sql, oracle

I will be running 30 separate MERGE statements which may or may not update records in 30 tables (1 table per MERGE statement).

How can I easily see how many rows each individual MERGE statement affected, using Aqua Data Studio?

I've been trying to use SQL%ROWCOUNT, but haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Text Results in the Query Window.
Then Go to File Options Results > Text Results and enable the options to suite your needs.
1. Always display 'records affected' count.
2. Display only the total number of affected records.

[image]

[image]